# Android Kotlin Proguard Obfuscation of Kotlin Default Impl

Tags: kotlin, proguard, android-r8, kapt

I use Android + Kotlin + Proguard

Code

```
inferface Authentication {
 val authenticated: Boolean
 val lastAuthentication: Instant

 fun authenticate(force: Boolean = false): Flow<Event>
 suspend fun revokeAccess() 
}
```

And an implementation of that interface

```
internal sealed class AuthenticationInternal(
 private val trustProvider: TrustProvider) : Authentication {
 override val authenticated: Boolean
    get() = trustProvider.authenticatedBefore()

 override val lastAuthentication: Instant
    get() = trustProvider.getLastAuthenticatedTime()

 override fun authenticate() = flow {
    trustProvider.checkIntegrity()
    emitAll(internalAuthenticate())
 }.flowOn(Dispatchers.Default)

 override suspend fun revokeAccess() {
    trustProvider.revokeAccess()
 }
}
```

-> During Kotlin Annotation Processing this interface gets (as expected) a default implementation:

**Kotlin generated code:**

Class: **Authentication$DefaultImpls.dex**

**-> Now my issue:**
Since this class is generated and not reachable from Kotlin code, how can I keep this class using progurard.

In my release build, this class is put out of the release dex and the application crashes with an RuntimeException.

Note:
Adding this to the proguard mappings file:
-keep class com.my.package.AuthenticationInternal$DefaultImpls { *; }
will not work, since it is not reachable

**How can I keep kapt-generated classes with proguard?**

Comment: The keep rule that you mention `-keep class com.my.package.AuthenticationInternal$DefaultImpls { *; }` should keep the class generated by `kotlinc`. Adding a keep rule makes the class always stay, and as kotlinc generates the class it should be in teh input to R8. Please file a bug on https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=326788 with details on your build setup, if you continue to have issues.

Comment: No that is not possible, since kapt generated classes can not be called from Kotlin code and also not from proguard file

Comment: The place where the class is generated should not matter, as the proguard file is applied to all code compiled. You can try to generate a [compiler dump](https://r8.googlesource.com/r8/+/1d07b2900464c95fbb57c54375cbd1873e394aff/doc/compilerdump.md), then you can see the code which is the actual input to R8.